# I'm having trouble in resetting my Windows 10

Tags: windows, bios, mbr, gpt

I wanted to reset my Windows with keeping the personal files. But during the half process it shows unable to reset this PC. So I thought of clean installing the Windows 10. What I want to know is that what's the procedure for it.

This are my system information.

4GB Ram, 1TB HHD, it is in GPT partition. And I think I have BIOS thing. And it doesn't have UEFI/BIOS boot option too. So I'm having so much confusion of GPT MBR, BIOS UEFI.

Last time when I installed the Windows it had some issue saying the partition is in GPT or MBR I don't what it was.

But I need clear steps of processing further.

Comment: Go here:   https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10   ....  Download the ISO, make a bootable USB Key, start with the USB key and install Windows 10 fresh.  Let it build the proper partitions.

Comment: Resting or Resetting? Those are two entirely different words

Comment: Thanks @John but as I said, the last time when I did the same process. I got en error like the driver cannot found. And then disk partition types error. So i don't know how to process

Comment: When you build the USB key and start from it, it will delete what is is there and make the the 3 normal partitions

Comment: Yup my bad didn't saw that one. Thanks @Ramhound for letting me know it .

Comment: @John okay I got that. My disk partition is in Gpt so does that mean I have to burn my usb in that format only.?

Comment: Just make the USB (it does not need a format type).  Start with it and delete all partitions. It will build the 3 correct partitions and use UEFI

Comment: @John sorry didn't get what you said. Can you explain me more clearly? Where are 3 partition getting created. And what do you mean by make the usb .?

Comment: Follow this guide   https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-create-windows-10-bootable-usb#:~:text=for%20digital%20purchases).-,How%20to%20Create%20Windows%2010%20Bootable%20USB%20Using%20Media%20Creation,for%20the%20installer%20to%20finish.  ... Then boot with the USB key.  Then Windows will create the partitions:   UEFI, Recovery and Data. You do not create your own partitions.

Comment: Okay thanks @John

Comment: Just use the Media Creation Tool.

Comment: @PadamGadshila - You must tell us the original error when you attempted to Reset your installation.  You can download the Windows 10 22H2 ISO directly from Microsoft, mount it within Windows, and perform a clean install from within Windows without much effort. Doing that will get you the exact same state as performing a Reset and NOT choosing to keep your files.  You can **try** performing an in-place repair of Windows and keeping your file, but doing so makes no sense if there isn't a reason you are performing the Reset in the first place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.